# Проблемы с работой curl

Tags: curl

Подскажите пожалуйста в таком вопросе.
Запись

```
$ch=curl_init("<https://bazar.bg/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%B8/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5?m_a=38&page=2>")
```

работает. Загружается страница с параметром `page=2` как и нужно. А вот если этот же урл записать в переменную

```
$qwe ="<https://bazar.bg/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%B8/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5?m_a=38&page=2>";
```

и подставить её в `curl_init()`

```
$ch = curl_init($qwe)
```

то загружается уже страница `1`, хотя прописан `page=2`.

Не пойму в чем дело.

Comment: Может что то с кавычками?

Comment: Ну так же не бывает. Вы точно копируете ссылку в переменную или что-то руками донабирали?

Comment: сам удивляюсь. Скопировал и вставил

Comment: может быть проблема в амперсанде? Надо её переводить в сущность?

Comment: Я повторил второй вариант и скачалась вторая страница

Comment: Можете написать свой код курла? У меня сейчас такой: $ch = curl_init($qwe); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_USERAGENT ,  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru-RU; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050919 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$content = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

Comment: Я даже UA не указывал. Просто вот так `$ch = curl_init($qwe);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
file_put_contents('2.html', $content);` класс `current` в загруженной странице указывает на вторую страницу. Без всяких преобразований URL

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему обработав `url` функцией `html_entity_decode()`.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: а что тут подробнее объяснять? Url, который выше в вопросе перед добавлением в curl_init() обработал функцией html_entity_decode и всё